# symfony json_respone withprefix

Tags: json, symfony

i create a route with json_respone function.
the code:

```
 /**
 * @Route("/app/homec")
 */
 public function HomeCatsAction(Request $request) {
    $list = $this->getDoctrine() 
        ->getRepository('AppBen2Bundle:HomeCategories')
        ->createQueryBuilder('e')
        ->getQuery()->getArrayResult();
    $response = new JsonResponse($list);
    $response->headers->set('Content-Type', 'application/json; charset=UTF-8');
    $response->setStatusCode(200);
        return $response;
 }
```

the json show it's fine, but no prefix.

exp:

```
{
    "id": 1,
    "h_name": "test",
    "h_des": "aaaaa",
    "h_des_sell": "",
    "h_des_full": "ssssss",
    "h_info": "",
    "pic": "",
    "order": 2
}
```

i want that the response will be:

```
home_categories": [
    {
        "id": 1,
        "h_name": "test",
        "h_des": "aaaaa",
        "h_des_sell": "",
        "h_des_full": "ssssss",
        "h_info": "",
        "pic": "",
        "order": 2
    }
]
```

my current symfony 2 version is 2.6
i try many solutions but the same result

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work:

```
$response = new JsonResponse(array('home_categories' => $list));
```